# Linq-to-SQL Retrieving child tables throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have database mapped with Linq-To-Sql class. I try to execute some basic queries on it and it fails with InvalidCastException when I try to access child tables.

```
var query = (from p in PBZGdb.Instance.AuthenticationDatas
                     where p.Username == "Misha" && p.Password == "123"
                     select new { p.UserAccount }).AsEnumerable();

UserAccount UA = query.ElementAt(0).UserAccount; //this works!
int count = UA.Characters.Count(); //throws InvalidCastException here
```

and

```
var query = (from p in PBZGdb.Instance.AuthenticationDatas
                     where p.Username == "Misha" && p.Password == "123"
                     select new
                     {
                         p.UserAccount,
                         p.UserAccount.Characters
                     }) .AsEnumerable();

UserAccount UA = query.ElementAt(0).UserAccount; //throws InvalidCastException here
```

If I just try to continue after exception paused the application after couple of seconds, it "retrieves" the data and proceeds no problem. Has anyone encountered something like this before? How do I solve it?

p.s. the Characters table is linked to UserAccounts with a foreign key. A UserAccount can have multiple Characters.

Comment: What provider do you use? Do you see the * real * SQL query in output?

Comment: What the type of your Password field?

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough information here; can you access an individual `Character` record, i.e. `var char = db.Characters.First()` ? I wonder if it is simply a column misconfigured (long vs int, or a dodgy enum value, etc)

Comment: unrelated: `p.Password` sets of alarm sounds.... should be a salted hash, really

Comment: @Morzel varchar (string)

Comment: @Tirgan yea I see a real SQL statement when I breakpoint and look at query. I am not sure about provider??

Comment: @Marc yea I know about the hash, this is just a test program to find out the problem.

Comment: @MichaelNaumov and on the other comment I added?

Comment: @Marc just tried it now, I got the InvalidCastException. I pressed resume and it worked after that. I am not sure whats going on..

Comment: @MichaelNaumov sounds to me like a column mismatch in the data. Check carefully that all the column/property maps are typed correctly (in particular enums, which are easily overlooked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I think I figured it!!! Its really strange and I am not sure why/what is happening but I pinpointed my error and can fix it now.

I generated my mapping .dbml file with sqlmetal. Next when I added it to the project I renamed it. But I think I renamed it inconsistently (in designer it was displaying as myMeta and in cs file it was named as myDB, and I was using myDB name everywhere else). And thats when all the problems start happening. As soon as I changed it back to original name, everything worked no problem!

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try this?

```
var query = (from p in PBZGdb.Instance.AuthenticationDatas
                 where p.Username == "Misha" && p.Password == "123"
                 select new { p.UserAccount }).AsEnumerable();

UserAccount UA = query.ElementAt(0).UserAccount; //this works!
var count = UA.Characters.Count(); //throws InvalidCastException here
```

(note var instead of int)

Comment: same exception. Whats more interesting is when I mouse over UA.Characters (or add watch expression) it will give InvalidCastException but if press Resume in VS couple of times it retrieves the correct value (which is 2) and proceeds fine.

Comment: <clutch at straw>Is the data context/model up to date? Perhaps what's coming back out of the database doesn't quite add up... Try re-dragging everything from the DB Again?</clutch at straw>

Answer (score 0):

Check your columns data types. Many times you get this error when trying to assign values in your columns to properties values.

try to keep the following mappings consistent.

```
SQL          .NET

bit       -> bool
tinyint   -> byte
smallint  -> short
int       -> int
bigint    -> long
decimal   -> decimal
money     -> decimal
float     -> double (preferred) | float
```

There are other inconsistent mappings that will throw the same error, but in my experience these are the most common cases.

The problem is that when LINQ-SQL populates your properties values it just assigns the value without converting it and you would get the same error as if you were trying to assign a `short` value to an `int` property.

Also check for possible null values. These properties should be nullables in your classes. `Nullable<int>` | `int?`